# Solve $x \circ a + x \circ (Bx) + c = 0$ for $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, hadamard-product

Is there a solution to $x \circ a + x \circ (Bx) + c = 0$ for $x$, where $B$ is an $N \times N$ matrix, $x$, $a$ and $c$ are $N \times 1$ column vectors, and $\circ$ is the Hadamard product (element-wise multiplication)? $a$, $B$, and $c$ are given, real, and non-zero. $B$ is also invertible.

Comment: I presume $a$, $B$ and $c$ are given.  Obviously there is no solution if $a = 0$ and $B = 0$ but $c \ne 0$.  So maybe the question should be, under what conditions can we guarantee the existence of a solution?

Comment: Are you looking for real solutions (where $a, B, c$ are real, or are complex solutions allowed?

Comment: Oh good point Robert Israel, I edited the question. Complex solutions are totally fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, let's take $N=2$.  The equation can be written as

$$ \eqalign{ b_{{1,1}}{x_{{1}}}^{2}+b_{{1,2}}x_{{1}}x_{{2}}+a_1 x_{{1}}
+c_{{1}} &= 0\cr
b_{{2,1}}x_{{1}} x_2 +b_{{2,2}}{x_{{2}}}^{2}+a_2 x_{{2}}
+c_{{2}} &= 0\cr} $$
The resultant with respect to $x_2$ is an irreducible quartic in $x_1$:

$$\left( {b_{{1,1}}}^{2}b_{{2,2}}-b_{{1,1}}b_{{1,2}}b_{{2,1}} \right) {
x_{{1}}}^{4}+ \left( 2\,a_{{1}}b_{{1,1}}b_{{2,2}}-a_{{1}}b_{{1,2}}b_{{
2,1}}-a_{{2}}b_{{1,1}}b_{{1,2}} \right) {x_{{1}}}^{3}+ \left( {a_{{1}}
}^{2}b_{{2,2}}-a_{{1}}a_{{2}}b_{{1,2}}+2\,b_{{1,1}}b_{{2,2}}c_{{1}}+{b
_{{1,2}}}^{2}c_{{2}}-b_{{1,2}}b_{{2,1}}c_{{1}} \right) {x_{{1}}}^{2}+
 \left( 2\,a_{{1}}b_{{2,2}}c_{{1}}-a_{{2}}b_{{1,2}}c_{{1}} \right) x_{
{1}}+b_{{2,2}}{c_{{1}}}^{2}
$$

Given a root $x_1$ of this,  you get $x_2$ by solving the first equation:

$$ x_{{2}}=-{\frac {b_{{1,1}}{x_{{1}}}^{2}+a_1 x_{{1}}+c_{{1}}}{b_{{1,
2}}x_{{1}}}}
$$
In general there will be four complex solutions.

For larger $N$, things will get horribly complicated if you try to do everything with symbolic coefficients, but I suspect there will be $2^N$ complex solutions in general.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. There's no simple way to do this I see. Thanks!